# Point Domain To Dedicated Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain

I have ordered a dedicated server and installed Windows server 2008 and managed to get it connected to the internet via IP address and also setup two role on it (IIS, DNS).

Now I want to point a domain (like example.com) that already registered to my IP address(dedicated server) but I can't make head or tale of any of the online help!

Can someone please explain this to me?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell IIS to watch for your domain. So to do this in 2008...

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Expand the Sites tree in the Connections pane on the left
3. In the Actions pane click on Bindings
4. Select the binding that you want to change (changes are it's set to your IP address or All IP Addresses on port 80)
5. Click edit or add and in the hostname box enter your domain name (example.com)
6. Click OK

The following is optional...

7. If you want www.example.com to work for your site then you should click add
8. Mirror the settings of the site above (i.e. select the IP or leave it as All IP Adresses on port 80)
9. In the hostname box enter www.example.com
10. Click OK
11. Then restart the site (not strictly necessary but worth doing)

Now you will be visit example.com (and if you did the optional stuff www.example.com) and your site should appear.

Explanation was adapted from information at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you, my problem is with DNS, because not correctly ns1 and ns2 addresses on the DNS server and domain not point to the server yet.

Comment: Ahh ok I assumed you had DNS sorted. Assuming the changes have been made on the name servers it should start working within 24 hours (normally much quicker if it's a new domain)

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct if anyone else comes across this question.